# Angular Using table Index for Cell Editing

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I have a table that has editable column. The issue is when I click on "Edit Icon" on a row, it enables input for all rows instead of the one I selected. Also same issue when I try to hide/show selected using "edit" flag. How can I add the index logic so it just show input field for the selectedrow?

**modal.html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-orange" (click)="onCancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
```

**modal.ts**

```
export class ModalComponent {
    @Output() edit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() cancelEdit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    showModal: boolean = true;
    onEdit() {
        // console.log("OK");
        this.edit.emit();
        this.showModal = false;
    }
    onCancelEdit() {
        // console.log("OK");
        this.cancelEdit.emit();
        this.showModal = true;
    }
}
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let bsa of bsaFollowup;let i=index" (click)="GetfollowupID(bsa.ID)">
    <td style="width:8%">{{bsa.ErsaID}}</td>
    <td style="width:18%">{{bsa.AccessFor}}</td>
    <td style="width:11%">
        {{bsa.FollowupDate}}
        <!--<datepicker-popup></datepicker-popup>-->
    </td>
    <td style="width:35%">
        <div *ngIf='edit'>{{bsa.Comments}}</div>
        <div><input type="text" [hidden]='!edit' id="comment" name="ucomment" [(ngModel)]="bsa.Comments" /></div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%">{{bsa.BsaName}}</td>
    <td style="width:15%">
        <modal (open)="onOpen($event)" (edit)="onEdit($event)" (cancelEdit)="onCancelEdit($event)"></modal>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**dashboard.ts** (the log shows the right *selectedRowID*)

```
onEdit() {
    console.log('on edit: ' + this.selectedRowID);
    this.edit = true;
    console.log('inside edit' + this.edit);
}
onCancelEdit() {
    console.log(this.selectedRowID);
    this.edit = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an `edit` flag, you could have an `editRowIndex`, which would target a specific row:

```
editRowIndex: number = -1;

onEdit(index: number) {
    this.editRowIndex = index;
}
onCancelEdit() {
    this.editRowIndex = -1;
}
```

The row index would be passed as an `@Input` value to the modal component, and propagated as the parameter of the `edit` event:

```
<modal [rowIndex]="i" (open)="onOpen($event)" (edit)="onEdit($event)" (cancelEdit)="onCancelEdit($event)"></modal>
```

```
export class ModalComponent {
    @Input() rowIndex: number = -1;
    @Output() edit: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() cancelEdit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    showModal: boolean = true;
    onEdit() {
        this.edit.emit(this.rowIndex);
        this.showModal = false;
    }
    onCancelEdit() {
        this.cancelEdit.emit();
        this.showModal = true;
    }
}
```

The input field would be displayed for the edited row:

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="i === editRowIndex" [(ngModel)]="bsa.Comments" ... />
```

Comment: Is it really OK? I was editing my answer since I feel that the row index is not passed correctly in the modal.

Comment: Good. :-) I modified my answer to pass the row index in a way that seems more appropriate to me. If that happens to breaks the execution, I will rollback my changes.

Comment: Actually, I have already tried that and it did not work...only worked with  (edit)="onEdit(i)" not  (edit)="onEdit($event)"

Comment: Even if you pass the row index as an input value to the modal, and then as the value of the emitted `edit` event (as shown above)?

Comment: ahhhhh, i missed one step (this.edit.emit(this.rowIndex);)...yes it worked ...great catch